# Google colab Local runtime GPU usage?

Tags: windows-10, gpu

i have Quadro P3000 GPU on a windows 10 system. I want to use google colab for writing my python code on local runtime.

How do i ensure that GPU acceleration is used?

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab is one of Google online service, and I do not think it is something that you can install on your local machine. I guess what you are looking for is probably Jupyter notebook and TensorFlow. Try Anaconda Python `tensotflow-gpu`. It would be the easiest way to use TensorFlow with GPU on a local machine.

Comment: See here for details about connecting to a local runtime with Colab (while the editor itself is presumably still served by Google online). https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html . However, I'm not sure if it's possible to use GPU support etc